# C# Comparing float to int

Tags: c#, floating-point, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have seen this code floating around on the intertubes for determining if a Windows Mobile device has a VGA screen (code is inside a method of a Form class):

```
SizeF currentScreen = this.CurrentAutoScaleDimensions;
bool isVGA = currentScreen.Height == 192;
```

Is it possible that isVGA could be set to false even if the screen is VGA because of float imprecision (the Height property is a float)?

Comment: So I gather your question is actually whether or not CurrentAutoScaleDimensions can return a non-integer float value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in the example you present, because (IEEE 754-compliant, 32-bit) floating-point numbers [can accurately represent all integers (whole numbers) whose absolute value is less than or equal to 2^24](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754%3a_floating_point_in_modern_computers).

Comment: Nice answer! You got straight to the point. If I was really paranoid I would worry about if I can be guaranteed that everyone will follow this standard. I would guess that it is reasonable to assume that everyone would at least follow the standard closely enough to accurately represent small, positive integers as floats. Is that right?

Comment: @INTPnerd: It's worthwhile to verify that your programming language of choice complies with this (extremely common) standard. C# does, according to the 3.0 specification: *The two floating point types, float and double, are represented using the 32-bit single-precision and 64-bit double-precision IEEE 754 formats.*